# How to create a navigation drawer in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have Home, Categories, and About pages and I want to create a navigation drawer and have access to all these pages in my navigation drawer, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To start, you'll need to install the "react native navigation drawer" library like so `npm install @react-navigation/drawer`

Once you've done that, add this code to your App.js file, or whatever page you want to have it on.

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Where `<Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />` represents each screen you want to add to the drawer.